Definition of Ricci flow
My undergraduate thesis is related to the Ricci flow, and I have a number of basic questions.
Let $M$ be a smooth manifold.
At the start of Chapter 2.3 of Peter Topping's Lectures on the Ricci flow, he supposes that $g$ is a smooth family of Riemannian metrics on $M$ defined on an open interval.
Question 1.  Does Peter mean that $g$ is a map of the form $g:I \times M \rightarrow T^{(0,2)}TM$, where $I\subseteq \mathbb R$ is an open interval? Does smoothness here mean that $g$ is smooth as a map between the smooth manifolds $I \times M$ and $T^{(0,2)}TM$?
I'm trying to write the definition of the Ricci flow in my own words. This is what I have: Let $I$ be an open interval, and let $g:I \times M \rightarrow T^{(0,2)}TM$ be a smooth (in the sense of Question 1) family of metrics. For each $p \in M$, we have a smooth curve $g(\cdot,p):I \rightarrow T^{(0,2)}T_p M$ given by $t \mapsto g(t,p)$. For each $t \in I$, define $(\partial_t g)(t,p) := g(\cdot,p)'(t)$. Since $T^{(0,2)}T_p M$ is a vector space, we can view $g(\cdot,p)'(t)$ as an element of $T^{(0,2)}T_p M$. We say that $g$ is a solution to the Ricci flow if
$$(\partial_t g)(t,p) = -2 \text{Ric}(g(t,p)) \qquad \forall (t,p) \in I \times M.$$
Question 2. Is my definition correct? Does the solution of the Ricci flow need to be smooth in the sense of Question 1?
Theorem A.15 of The Ricci Flow: Techniques and Applications Part I states the following:

Theorem 1. If $(M,g_0)$ is a closed Riemannian manifold, then there exists a unique solution $g(t)$ to the Ricci flow defined on some positive time interval $[0, \varepsilon)$ such that $g (0) = g_0$.

Question 3. In the theorem above, what does it mean for the solution $g:[0,\varepsilon) \times M \rightarrow T^{(0,2)}TM$ to be smooth? Does it mean that $g$ is smooth as a map between smooth manifolds, where $[0,\varepsilon) \times M$ is considered as a manifold with boundary? Or does it mean that $g$ is continuous, and smooth on $(0,\varepsilon) \times M$? Or does it mean something else?
On the other hand, the wikipedia page on the Ricci flow states that Hamilton proved the following theorem:

Theorem 2. If $(M,g_0)$ is a closed Riemannian manifold, then there exists a positive number $T$ and a Ricci flow $g_t$ parameterised by $t \in (0,T)$ such that $g_t$ converges to $g_0$ in the $C^\infty$ topology as $t \rightarrow 0$.

Question 4. What is the relationship between Theorem 1 and Theorem 2? Does one follow from the other?
I tried looking at the original paper by Hamilton, but I wasn't able to understand it.

Thm1 with your (perfectly natural) interpretation implies Thm2 and seems stronger (I have no idea whether it's true)

Have you tried consulting other sources, such as the book by Chow et al? https://www-ams-org.proxy.library.nyu.edu/books/gsm/077/

@Deane I'm not able to access the link you sent. Are you referring to the book Hamilton's Ricci Flow by Ben Chow, Lei Ni, and Peng Lu?

@JosephKwong, yes

Questions 1, 2: Yes, your explanations are correct. Since this description is rather abstract, I prefer to write it all out in local coordinates. Then the definitions are much more straightforward, because they involve just real-valued functions on an open subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$.
Q3: It is unfortunate that the initial definitions above assume an open interval. They all also hold for any type of nonempty connected interval. You don't need to define a manifold with boundary. If you write it all in local coordinates, then the Ricci flow looks like a map
$$F: [a,b) \times O \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^N,$$ where $O \subset\mathbb{R}^n$ is open. Given what you've said, it's unclear to me what the assumptions are on $g_t$ in Theorem 1. It appears to be your second guess.
Q4: Yes, Theorem 1 is a consequence of Theorem 2. But it looks like Topping proves Theorem 1 first. Theorem 2 is not a direct consequence of Theorem 1. However, it is straightforward to apply the proof of Theorem 1 to not just the Ricci flow itself but also to the nonlinear heat equation satisfied by all of the covariant derivatives (with respect to the metric $g_0$) of $g_t$.

It seems odd to me that Theorem 1 does not imply Theorem 2, could you elaborate?

So would it converge in the $C^1$ topology?

It depends on what the precise statement of Theorem 1 is and its proof. For example, if tf the proof proves only that, with respect to $t$ ,$_t$ is continuous on $[0,\epsilon)$, and smooth on $(0,\epsilon)$, then it does not imply that $\partial_tg_t$ is continuous on $[0,\epsilon)$. This is the kind of thing that you have to be very precise about. You need to read Topping's exact statements of the theorem and his proofs very very carefully.

@Deane Thanks alot for your response! I have two follow-up questions: 1. What does it mean for a map $F:[a,b) \times O \rightarrow \mathbb R^n$ to be smooth? I've always thought smoothness of $F$ in this case to be smoothness in the sense of a manifold with boundary. 2. Could you explain why Theorem 2 implies Theorem 1? (I don't know much about the $C^\infty$ topology and unfortunately the wikipedia page wasn't insightful to me.)

I apologize. My answer is not quite right. And Topping is indeed doing things correctly. I'll edit my answer when I find some time.
